# Laptop doesn't turn on at all after installing Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, boot, power-management

Long story short, my buddy was running Windows 8 on Lenovo G510 for 4 years, and was always complaining how it was lagging. I suggested to switch to Linux, he tried Linux Mint Live CD for a few hours, was happy about it, and decided to install it over the Windows partition - meaning he chose "erase disk" during the install process.

After powering on Linux Mint from HDD he was able to browse around only for 2 minutes and then everything went dark, and the laptop does not boot anymore - no power/battery lights are on.

What could have happened, and could Linux actually have caused it?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a hardware issue.

I can't see how any operating system could cause this; it might not boot, but it will still turn on (and you should get a BIOS). Even without a drive at all, you get *something*.

Try unplugging + taking out the battery, then press the power button and wait a few minutes before plugging it back in to see if it comes back. If not, I'd try calling Lenovo's support.

Comment: Well yes, it is a hardware issue, when not even battery or power indicator lights up, it's obvious - but it's natural to think that installing Linux caused this issue either directly or indirectly. I'm just trying to figure out how.

Comment: I see what you mean, it happened right after so it feels like there should be a connection but i can't think of anything that might cause this from an os install. It probably was just bad timing.

Comment: Yes, this is just one more example of a *post hoc ergo propter hoc* fallacy.